# How to implement oneway RPC calls via ZeroMQ

Tags: ipc, zeromq, messaging, rpc, thrift

In our distributed system there are native and .NET components, there is a broker that acts both as a network topology explorer and as a message router.
Transport and serialization is provided by in-house developed component - it's ugly and buggy.

I'm looking for solutions that provide RPC or messaging and also serialization.

I don't need **`AMQP`** broker, because it would require additional administration of exchanges and queues.

Also I don't need persistence for messages in the system - every such message has value only in real-time.

I know that **`Thrift`** offers RPC and also serialization - it works for me only partially, because some communication in our system is based on the **`PUB`**/**`SUB`** pattern, and `Thrift` isn't suitable for this.

Which of the **`ZeroMQ`** messaging pattern is suitable for oneway ( async ) calls?

Some components in our system do one way requests ( this is not data distribution, so the `ZeroMQ` `PUB`/`SUB` sockets are not suitable here, as I think ).

`ZeroMQ` **`REQ`**/**`REP`** sockets are not the option too. Maybe some other patterns?

Comment: You already eliminated Thrift because it does not support PUB/SUB and you don't want to use both. So essentially, the only thing left is the question: **What pattern should I choose to make simple RPC calls via ZMQ?** Can it be summarized correctly this way? Then you should modify the question accordingly.

Comment: You can use dealer to dealer or push pull. But if you have both two way and one way I suggest to use dealer-router. Just don't reply when the message is one way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to describe my solution, which works fine. As @somdoron adviced, I use *DEALER-ROUTER* combination in order to send requests (both synchronous and oneway).

The architecture is the folowing:

- **Frontend** has *DEALER* socket to make requests and *SUBSCRIBER* socket to receive events. Frontend knows only about broker.
- **Broker** has 3 sockets: *ROUTER* - to receive requests (and to send back responces, if required); *PUBLISHER* - to distribute requests for backend services responsible for processing, and also to distribute events; *PULL* - to receive results of processing from backend.
- **Backend** services (each service has different functionality, also they can communicate with each other via **broker**) have 3 sockets to correspond broker's sockets. *SUBSCRIBER* - to receive commands (requests) from broker. *DEALER* - to send requests (or notifications) to other backend services. *PUSH* - to transfer results of processing to broker.

How it works, in details.

1. Frontend's DEALER sent multipart message to broker: `M{frame[0]=command, frame[1]=body}`
2. ROUTER received message from frontend: `FM{frame[0]=Identity, frame[1]=command, frame[2]=body}`
3. Transform message FM in order to publish to backend: `PM{frame[0]=command, frame[1]=Identity, frame[2]=body}`, then PUBLISHER would distribute this modified message for backend
4. Backend's subscriber received such message (PM - see above), and backend perform processing
5. When message is processed, if responce is required, backend would create it as responce message `RM{frame[0]=Identity, frame[1]=result}` and use PUSH socket to send result to broker
6. Broker's PULL socket would receive result and pass it to ROUTER, so result message `RM{frame[0]=Identity, frame[1]=result}` would be delivered to frontend identified by Identity.

Comment: I use separate PUSH-PULL to transfer results from backend to broker, because I don't want to create complex logic on ROUTER.

If backend service A, in order to process request, need to make additional request to another service B, it would do it on the same scheme, which frontend uses.